# How do I remove chrx on an ASUS Chromebook C202SA?

Tags: partition, chrome-os

I already tried recovering with a recovery USB stick, but it does nothing. Now I'm stuck with 19.8 MB of storage. I can't even figure out what partition(s) to delete. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, doing a full recovery is the only way to re-partition your Chromebook back to the OEM sizes and structure and regain the space that was allotted to Gallium OS. The best tool for that is the [Chromebook Recovery Utility](http://Chromebook%20Recovery%20Utility).

A powerwash removes all user data including wiping out any crouton chroots so you do get some space back but it doesn't re-partition your Chromebook like a full recovery.

**UPDATE**

You could also try (ON YOUR OWN RISK):

1. Get into crosh (ctrl - alt - t), then into your shell by typing `shell`
2. Type `sudo fdisk -l` - this lists your different partitions. Find the partition which you set aside for `chrx`; it will be labeled as "ChromeOS root fs" or similar. Make sure the size matches up to the amount you gave chrx.
3. Type `sudo fdisk /(wherever your partitions are stored)` - I believe this changes according to the different type of Chromebook you use.
4. Type `d`. The system will ask you which partition you want to delete. Usually, `chrx` is installed on partition 7, but that could also vary on different Chromebooks.
5. Type `d` again. This time, delete where all of your files. This might be  labeled as `Microsoft basic data`, and the file size will match up to the amount Chrome OS says you have (in the Files app).
6. Type `n`. This time, you're going to recreate the `Files` partition you deleted.
7. Unless you have a preference as to which sectors the Files app should take up, just use default.
8. Type `t`. This time, you need to rename the Files partition to what it was before because it automatically is named Linux Partition.
9. Type `L` to list all the different types of partitions, and type in the number next to Microsoft basic data.
10. Finally, type `w`, and reboot the system. This officially commits all of your changes.

ChromeOS might get angry you try to change partitions and may hang in "fixing the system" for some time. However, after some time, it should boot up again.

Comment: Sorry, but I already tried that, and I'm still stuck. Do you know any other ways?

Comment: @GabryllePanlaqui, added an update to my reply, might work for you, but it's more risky.